# How to escape from file browsing mode?

Tags: buffers, netrw

I just found out that we can use 
`:e .` to enter the browsing mode and then can choose file what we like.

[image: vim]

But I don't know how to get back to already opened file without choosing it again.

I tried `<Esc>` and `:q` but the first one doesn't work and second closes the file I have opened already (`.vimrc` in my case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use any of Vim's many buffer-switching commands to return to the file you were previously working on.

Here's a few possibilities:

- Use the `:buffer` command to jump to the alternate buffer: `:b #`
- Use the normal mode command to jump to the alternate buffer: `<C-^>`
- Just step back through the jump list till you get there: `<C-O>`

As [Peter Rincker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/778/peter-rincker) points out in a comment below, you can also use the dedicated `:Rexplore` command provided by the file explorer plugin (netrw) itself to do this: `:Rex` will return you to the file you were editing previously if run from explorer view (and will conversely return you back *to* the explorer view if you subsequently run it from a normal buffer).

Comment: You can use `:Rex` to resume exploring right where you left off

Comment: Those who try to `:Rex` when you were previously in a `[No Name]` buffer may think isn't working, and that's correct. If it's by design, it seems bad because someone may have stuff typed in that buffer. You can use `:b #` in that case, though. Note: only if that `[No Name]` buffer wasn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

as [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) has mentioned, we can use 
`:b<buffer_number>` to jump to a buffer,
we can see `buffer_number` using command `:list`

In my case I just wanted to go to previous buffer/file, so we can use

```
:bp
```

this will get us to the previously edited buffer,

Thanks, [icc97](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/11986/icc97), [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) and everyone....
`#Happy coding`

Comment: Note that this command won't always have the effect of returning to the file you were in before entering netrw: it steps back through the buffer list, which is ordered according to when the buffers were *created*, not when they were most recently visited.

Comment: So, which command can help me with that specific problem,
I do not want to dive deep into any of tool, as I am very new to VIM,
and do not want to get overwhelmed.